# How to make emacs smoothly scroll

Tags: emacs, elisp

I've used emacs for some time, the most inconvenience of emacs for me is that it doesn't scroll smoothly when I'am reading the source code by the mouse's scroll button, though some configuration do thing similarly, it still can't make emacs scroll as vim,browsers,etc. How can I make it, should I hack the source code of emacs, if someone did that, please let me know, it has confused me for such a long time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried this: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SmoothScrolling